# Why is my ANTLR grammar file for Java not compiling?

Tags: java, eclipse, antlr, antlrworks

I have been given an ANTLR grammar for a subset of the Java compiler known as the static Java compiler. I am trying to extend the grammar to include more of Java's features, for instance, I just added the grammar for *For Loops*.

Using Eclipse and an ANTLR plugin, I then did 'Compile ANTLR grammar'. Instead of compiling it produced two errors on the first bit of code:

```
grammar ExtendedStaticJava;

options { backtrack=true; memoize=true; }

@header
{
package sjc.parser.extended;
import java.math.BigInteger;

/**
 * Extended StaticJava parser.
 * @author <myname>
 */
}

// the rest of the grammar has been excluded.
```

The first error is on line 1: 'Unexpected Token: grammar'
The second error is on line 5: 'Unexpected char: @'

Why does it not recognize this basic ANTLR syntax? My first thought was that I was missing something in the classpath, but I went to the project's properties and made sure that the following JARs were included under *Libraries*:

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
- antlr.jar
- antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`antlr-2.7.7.jar` is wrong: your grammar is in ANTLR v3+ syntax. Remove all:

- antlr-2.7.7.jar
- stringtemplate-3.2.1.jar
- antlr.jar
- antlr-runtime-3.0.1.jar

from your project/classpath and only stick [this ANTLR v3 JAR](http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-3.2.jar) in it (which contains everything you need: runtime, stringtemplate, the works!).

Good luck!

---

### EDIT

Personally, I do my IDE integration with an Ant build script. I generate a lexer and parser like this:

```
<target name="generate.parser" depends="init" description="Generates the lexer, parser and tree-walker from the grammar files.">
    <echo>Generating the lexer and parser...</echo>
    <java classname="org.antlr.Tool" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="-fo" />
        <arg value="${main.src.dir}/${parser.package}" />
        <arg value="${parser.grammar.file}" />
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </java>
    <!-- snip -->
</target>
```

and the `classpath` `refid` looks like:

```
<path id="classpath">
    <!-- snip -->
    <fileset dir="lib">
        <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
```

and the `lib/` directory contains the ANTLR v3 JAR (no other ANTLR JARs! (sorry for hammering on that `:)`))

Comment: It didn't seem to work. In Eclipse I right clicked the project, selected properties, then Java Build Path -> Libraries. From here I removed all the jars you listed above and added antlr-3.2.jar which is from the link you provided. It is giving me the same errors as before.

Comment: @Treebranch, the only advice I can giove is if you're not 100% sure of how tools work with each other, don't use the tools. In your case, you're not 100% sure how Eclipse and ANTLR interact: don't use them together, but use ANTLR with the command line instead. I can tell you one thing: I am sure your 2.7 JAR is wrong with the snippet of the grammar you posted, and separate runtime- or stringtemplate libraries are not necessary with the JAR I linked. Best of luck!

Comment: @Treebranch, if you post your grammar, I can show you how to generate a parser and lexer in the command line without a problem!

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but it isn't that I am not able to generate the parser and lexer. I can do that with ANTLRWorks actually. The problem is that I want it in Eclipse so that I can run my JUnit tests against it.

Comment: @Treebranch, ah, I see. Check my EDIT, in that case. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

You have probably installed the [AntlrEclipse plugin](http://antlreclipse.sourceforge.net/). This indeed uses Antlr 2.7.something. There is however a plugin available that works with v3, [Antlr IDE](http://antlrv3ide.sourceforge.net/). This plugin is a little bit more advanced as it allows you to configure the Antlr version (3+) and can show a railroad view and has an interpreter.

> *Note* If you are using Eclipse Juno, you will need to install the DLTK from the Indigo repositorties, as 4.0.0 is to new for the antlr plugin

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue as well.

At some point during my attempts to get antlr running I had added some version of the jar file to my classpath windows environment variable. I removed this entry, and it resolved my issue.